# How to draw disabled text with TextRenderer.DrawText

Tags: c#, winforms

How to draw disabled text with `TextRenderer.DrawText` (or similar function)? I tried `ControlPaint.DrawStringDisabled` but the character spacing is not right.

Note: It seems that the character spacing in `ControlPaint.DrawStringDisabled` and `Graphics.DrawString` are the same.

Comment: Are you tried use correct font?

Comment: Yes, I just pass in the font that is already set in the control.